# I want add ruby hash to a yaml file(need to add value to the same keys repeatedly)

Tags: ruby, hash

I tried to write a yaml file from a hash using ruby. And am able to create the yaml file.

The program is just a report that i tried to create. But the real problem occurred is that it works perfectly for one date. When I tried to run the on day1, its work perfectly(the yaml file is created correctly), but when i tried to run on another date, the values in the yaml files are overwrite, but actually I want to add the new value with the previous one in the yaml.

I know my english is bad and sometimes little lack to create logics. Please help me to correct the issue. The code is below

```
def write_monthly_yaml_file(daily_data)
  @daily = File.exist?(@monthly_yaml_file) ? YAML::load_file(@monthly_yaml_file) : Hash.new
  @daily[Time.parse(@date).strftime("%m")] = daily_data
  File.open(@monthly_yaml_file, "w") {|f| f.puts @daily.to_yaml}  
end
```

here daily_data is the hash, will anyone please help me to add new daily_data with old one(I need to add each value with previous value like summing)

Thank you

Comment: You can use the YAML::Store class, which is part of Ruby standard library. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML/Store.html

Comment: Could you show us structure of `daily_data`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to have many entries for one month:

```
# the line below overwrites the value for the key given
# @daily[Time.parse(@date).strftime("%m")] = daily_data

# will collect all data in an array instead:
(@daily[Time.parse(@date).strftime("%m")] ||= []) << daily_data
```

Here we create an array as a value unless it existed and *append* the `daily_data` value to it. For this code to be run successfully, please remove your existing yaml file from the disk.

The reason is that currently there is a single instance of `daily_data` associated with the key and the interface changed.

Comment: i just not need to append, i just want to sum each time

Comment: Sum? What do you mean “sum”? Did you try the solution above? What’s wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If your data in @daily[day] is a number you want to add to, try this:

```
 @daily = File.exist?(@monthly_yaml_file) ?   
YAML::load_file(@monthly_yaml_file) : Hash.new
day = Time.parse(@date).strftime("%m")
@daily[day] = (@daily[day] + daily_data)
File.open(@monthly_yaml_file, "w") {|f| f.puts @daily.to_yaml}
```

Comment: if i run the program on 18/7/2016, i want all data write to the yml file on the same date. Then, when i need to run the program on 19th, i want the data on 19th will add with of 18th. Can you change the code , it will be a help